# Rails collection_select different selected attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have a `collection_select` with options from other model, and I need to show in the dropdown and in selected value different attributes. I.e I need to show in dropdown `object.title` but the selected value should show `object.code`.
I have a code:

```
f.collection_select :some_attribute_id, Country.all, :id, :title
```

Currently showing values in dropdown and showing selected value are the same attribute. I have tried to do something like

```
f.collection_select :some_attribute_id, Country.all, :id, :title, { prompt: @object.country.code }
```

or `selected: @object.country.code` but unsuccessful

Comment: To select you need to use the same thing you use to identify the correct country, in your case `:id` so selected should point to `{selected: @object.country.id`. If you want the form to submit the `:code` instead, then use this in both places: `f.collection_select :some_attribute_id, Country.all, :code, :title, {selected: @object.country.code}`

Comment: to show the `selected` you need to use the `id`. 
i.e. `f.collection_select :some_attribute_id, Country.all, :id, :title, {selected: @object.country.id}`

Comment: I need to have different attributes only for representation, i.e. in dropdown are shows titles of object but selected value represents code.